# Using Find method to Unhide columns

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am trying to unhide columns using input from user through a multiselect listbox.

I am running a loop to find out if a particular entry has been selected, and using the value of the selected entry to find it in a range and then unhiding the particular column.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sel As Range
Dim TagDump As Range
Dim strng As String
Dim lRow As Long

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tag Dump").Range("A:AQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Set TagDump = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tag Dump").Range("A1:AR1")

With Me.ListBox1
    For lRow = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(lRow) Then
            strng = .List(lRow, 0)
            With TagDump
                Set sel = .Find(What:=strng, after:=.Cells(1, 1))
                Debug.Print sel.Column
                sel.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End With
        End If
    Next lRow
End With
End Sub
```

However, when I run it I am getting Error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set.

I am using Debug.Print without running sel.Entirecolumn.Hidden to find out the index of the column and it is correctly showing me each time. But, when I run it along with that command line I am again getting the error.

Please let me know what is causing this and how can I rectify it.

Thank you.

EDIT: This is working fine for the first selected value and I'm able to unhide that column, but for subsequent values, it is showing the error.

Comment: I don't think Find() will work on hidden cells.  At least when using `lookin:=xlValues`

Comment: Sorry for omitting this in the question, but it is working fine for the first selected value, but for the subsequent values it is showing this error.

Comment: Try this - `Set sel = .Find(What:=strng, lookin:=xlFormulas,  after:=.Cells(1, 1))`

Comment: Not working, it is still showing the error.

Comment: Maybe try `Application.Match` instead of `Find`

Comment: Application.Match isn't working either. @TimWilliams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not hiding the columns until you've performed the Find's :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sel As Range, rngVis As Range
Dim TagDump As Range
Dim strng As String
Dim lRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tag Dump")    
Set TagDump = ws.Range("A1:AR1")

With Me.ListBox1
    For lRow = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(lRow) Then
            strng = .List(lRow, 0)
            With TagDump
                Set sel = .Find(What:=strng, after:=.Cells(1, 1))
                If not sel is nothing then 
                    Debug.Print strng, sel.Column
                    BuildRange rngVis, sel
                End If 
            End With
        End If
    Next lRow
End With

ws.Range("A:AQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
If Not rngVis is nothing then rngVis.entirecolumn.hidden = false 'unhide matches  

End Sub

Sub BuildRange(rngTot as Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot is nothing then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will show all selected columns and hide all others within the specified range. Please try it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' 013

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim VisClm As String
    Dim TagDump As Range
    Dim C As Long

    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tag Dump")
    Set TagDump = Ws.Range("A1:AR1")

    With Me.ListBox1
        For C = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(C) Then VisClm = VisClm & .List(C, 0) & "|"
        Next C
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With TagDump
        For C = 1 To .Columns.Count
            Ws.Columns(.Columns(C).Column).EntireColumn.Hidden _
                    = (InStr(1, VisClm, .Cells(1, C).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0)
        Next C
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've built this code on the assumption that the captions in the TagDump range as identical (even the RowSource) of the items in ListBox1. If the relationship is of another kind the code would need to be adapted to the reality in your worksheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Can you please explain to me, this line of code?
`Ws.Columns(.Columns(C).Column).EntireColumn.Hidden  = (InStr(1, VisClm, .Cells(1, C).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0)`

Comment: `(InStr(1, VisClm, .Cells(1, C).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0)` is a statement that evaluates to either True or False. You are probably quite familiar with it if used in an IF statement, like, `If(InStr(1, VisClm, .Cells(1, C).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0, [Hide], [Don't hide])`. Of course, the IF isn't necessary. You can compare strings like `If([String1]=[String2],..` How about case matching then? vbTextCompare in the Instr function specifies case insensitivity. Instr returns a number if the one string was found within the other, 0 if it wasn't.